# How to use variable on Enumerable in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

i really want to know is posible or not.

**Class**

```
public class XLRSV : AuditableEntity<long>
    {
        [DisplayName("INDEX")]
        public int IDX { get; set; }

        .
        .
        30 more
        .
        .

        [DisplayName("REMOTE STATUS")]
        public int EPSR_REMOTE_STATUS { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("SCAN STATUS")]
        public int EPSR_SCAN_STATUS { get; set; }
    }
```

**Repository**

```
IEnumerable<XLRSV> GetScanData(int id);
```

**Controller**

```
var result = _xlrsvSvr.GetScanData(id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Normaly use

```
int idx = result.IDX;
```

so, i want make list use variable on this

```
var column = from name in typeof(XLRSV).GetProperties()
                     select name;

        List<object> columnName = new List<object>();
        List<object> columnDisplayName = new List<object>();

        MemberInfo cname;
        MemberInfo cDispName;

        foreach (var item in column)
        {
            cname = typeof(XLRSV).GetProperty(item.Name);
            columnName.Add(cname.Name);

            cDispName = typeof(XLRSV).GetProperty(cname.Name);
            columnDisplayName.Add(cDispName.CustomAttributes.Select(x => x.NamedArguments.Select(y => y.TypedValue.Value)).OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute>());                
        }
```

now i'm using this code

```
new {name = "IDX", displayName = columnDisplayName[0].ToString(), result=result.IDX, checkPoint=""},
new {name = "EPSR_UNIQUE_NUMBER", displayName = columnDisplayName[1].ToString(), result=result.EPSR_UNIQUE_NUMBER, checkPoint=""},
.
.over 30 more
.
new {name = "EPSR_SCAN_STATUS", displayName = columnDisplayName[22].ToString(), result="", checkPoint=""},
```

So, I want to use for loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i< columnName.count()) {
    new {
    name = columnName[i].toString(), 
    displayName = columnDisplayName[i].ToString(), 
    result=result.columnName[i].toString(),  //here i want to use varialbe
    checkPoint=""
    },
}
```

i couldn't find way. is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't the most clear but I believe I understand what you're trying to accomplish. I believe this is a simple matter of reflection. it seems you have most of what you need other than `DisplayName`.

Below I've created a function you can place on your `XLRSV` class and a class to help you retrieve the information I believe you want. See the comments for a description of each function/class purpose.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

// This will grab the desired info for each public instance property on the class.
// Put this function inside your XLRSV. If you can't change XLRSV adjust this to be
// a method extension.
public IEnumerable<ObjectPropertyInfo<XLRSV>> GetObjectPropertyInfo()
{
    var type = typeof(XLRSV);
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var list = new List<ObjectPropertyInfo<XLRSV>>();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        list.Add(new ObjectPropertyInfo<XLRSV>(property, this));
    }
    return list;
}

// This will represent the data you want and given the property info and object
// will retrieve and set all the values as needed. It appears you had most of this
// figured out other than the DisplayName which is retrieved via GetCustomAttribute.
public class ObjectPropertyInfo<T> where T : class
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string CheckPoint { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a ClassInfo given a property name and an object from which to retrieve the value.
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectPropertyInfo(PropertyInfo propInfo, T obj)
    {
        if (propInfo == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("propInfo was null."); }

        Name = propInfo.Name;
        DisplayName = GetDisplayName(propInfo);
        Result = GetValue(propInfo, obj);
        CheckPoint = "";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the display name of the property if one is available.
    /// </summary>
    private string GetDisplayName(PropertyInfo propInfo)
    {
        if (propInfo == null) { return null; }

        var displayNameAttr = propInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>();
        if (displayNameAttr == null) { return propInfo.Name; }

        return displayNameAttr.DisplayName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the value of an object given which property.
    /// </summary>
    private string GetValue(PropertyInfo propInfo, T obj)
    {
        if (propInfo == null) { return null; }
        return propInfo.GetValue(obj)?.ToString();
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: really thanks for comment.
I'm just started MVC5.
so.. Can you fix the code 

    foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            list.Add(property, this); // here is error -> can not use 2args.
        }

Comment: Whoops forgot to new up an instance of the class. Take this opportunity to do a code review yourself. Make sure that what I have wrote works in every case you need, if not do what you need to fix it. Make sure it does what you expect and return/throw something if not. Etc. Etc. Check that, 3 months from now, you understands what each of these functions are supposed to do via the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much!. This is exactly what i'm looking for.
you saved my life. thank you for code and advice!